# Solve logical error in this assembly program

Tags: assembly, x86, dos

A program in assembly language which calculate the sum of product of two series defined as:

`Total = Submission (where i=from 0 to n) S1(i)*S2(i)`

Where:

```
S1: DW 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
S2: DW 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11
```

My effort:

```
[org 0x0100]

jmp start


s1: dw 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
s2: dw 20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11
total: dw 0

subroutine: 
       mov si,0
       mov cx,10

label: mov ax,[bx+si]
       mov dx,[bx+si]
       mul ax
       add [total],ax
       add bx,2
       dec cx
       shl cx,1
       jnz label

       mov cx,[total]
       ret

start: mov bx,s1
       mov dx,s2
       mov cx,10
       call subroutine

       mov ax,0x4c00
       int 0x21
```

Comment: hint: Check your sources.. and multipliers.. and counters. Also be sure to get yourself a debugger or at least a monitor as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
   dec cx
   shl cx,1
   jnz label
```

`CX` starts as 10, becomes 9, 18, jump
next loop: 18, 17, 34, jump
next loop: 34, 33, 66, jump
next loop: 66, 65, 130, jump

see the problem now?

Hint : the `LOOP` command decrements `CX` and jumps if not zero...

Answer (score 0):

I see a number of issues here:

1. You set `cx` twice, once before calling the function and once *in* the function. This does not cause an actual problem but it's supefluous.
2. You load both `ax` *and* `dx` with `[bx+si]`. Presumably, those are supposed to be from the *individual* lists `s1` and `s2` so you'll need another way (register) to track the other list.
3. Your `shl cx,1` is not needed - it basically doubles `cx` meaning that the preceding `dec cx` is not going to help much toward getting closer to zero :-)